# Appending Pandas DataFrame repeatedly

Tags: python, pandas

I have code that produces two probabilities along with error. I want to add the three items as a new row to a DataFrame every time I run the algorithm.

I have tried running a for loop with append and concat, but
I run into the problem that it does not append or it appends the previous output of the code instead of the new output and then stops. My code is supposed to run about 50 times and append each run to the DataFrame but I am stuck. Any suggestions?

(The Nuance is that I have re-run the code to get the new entries for the DataFrame then try to add them without messing up the previous entries.)

Comment: It is better to collect the data in a list and append it all in one call. Build your list of lists/dicts with `temp.append([a, b, c,])` if you have three columns in df, then after the loop is done call `df.append(temp)`

Comment: try `pd.concat([a, b, c])`

Comment: When I run the code to get the new data would that then just override the previous entry?

Comment: will that work even when I have to manually re-run the code to get the new data @RichieV

Comment: You mean if you want to run another 50 tests? Try [saving the df to a file], if you don't have loads of tests then a csv should be fine

Comment: Yes I have to run the code manually 50 times and I am concerned that the variables will override each other after each run. @RichieV

Comment: You can [save the df](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html)